# color management: prefilter

Tags: color-management

Color management influences before the nodes. Is it right?

In [this scene](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WEV7nIeQ4fnbBC-yAZPlLtAdxa1WOSv2/view?usp=sharing) - 100% white circles look like shades of gray. In [Addition blend mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Addition) - they become translucent.

But in this case - translucency occurs only if the "mix" node receives a color other than white. Yet I didn't send gray in the first place: I send 100% white. This means that the filter affects the color before it enters the "mix" node. Right?

[This article](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/3.1/render/color_management.html) doesn't describe enough about the route and behavior. I assumed that the filter should be post, not pre. But apparently the filter is more complicated (otherwise it's a bug?)

And if indeed the filter works at the beginning - this is important to keep in mind, at least when working with a mask. Otherwise, you may get unpredictable results.

[image]

Comment: Are you in Filmic, where pure white is about 16.29?

Answer (score 1):

### Color management are not influences the image value.

So, it influences after the nodes

In your case. You will see the highest pixle value of Filmic and Standard are same as 2.0.

If you use Standard, there is no problem to set both `1.0`
If you use Filmic, you need set higher than `16.19`

[image]

Comment: it doesn't solve.

Please, check how `Clamp` affects on rendered image,
this is compare two splitted images: [screenshot](https://i2.paste.pics/6d875a7dc5020da1af0ad3e998ff51b6.png).

Blend.file of demo-scene, [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xuJPbsNvmVBx2LMTfkR039IYlqtarBWR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I update a solution for you.